# XCode How to Archive and Export without a paid Dev Account

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode8

I have `Xcode Version 8.2.1 (8C1002)`. I do not have a paid for developer account yet, so this may be the reason for my problem. However, my questions is, is it possible to export an `ipa` if you don't have a paid for dev account?

I am able to `Archive` my project:

[image]

However, when I go to, `Window -> Organizer`, there are no `archives`:

[image]

**Questions**

1. Are there no Archives because I don't have a paid for developers account? You can see there are no `Provisioning Profiles`, which I guess you need a paid for dev account to create?
2. Is there a way to create an ipa file without the paid for account?

(I am on a limited budget, and need to send an ipa to someone's iPhone who will help me with the look and feel of the app, before I sign up to a 1 years subscription with Apple. I don't want to waste subscription time on development.)

Comment: You can't export and distribute IPA without paid developer account

Comment: That means you can't develop for free. That's a stingy model Apple have adopted. At least in Android, you can deploy and apk to a devise for free, only when you want to deploy to the Play Store or make use of their In App Purchases do you have to pay a subscription to use their services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's impossible. what's more, that app has an In-app purchase feature.